# Manipulating array out of bounds, can't seem to understand implications

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int array[5] = {0};
array[6] = 100;
std::cout << array[6];
}
```

This gave output 100
How does this work? Aren't we supposed to not go out of bounds for arrays?
Even if i went out of bounds here things work perfectly fine. What does array "bound" actually mean and what's its use ?

Compiler used- GNU GCC compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Undefined Behavior. You can get a crash or you are lucky that it did not happened. Ideally `array[5]` assigned `5` ints of memory on the stack which the program can access in its space but `array[6]` is not under program memory space can be assigned to some other program.  In fact, you still wont normally damage something unless you are writing someone's programmable location that is not `re-writable`.

Writing data to some random memory location you don't own will not directly `damage` any other program running on your system as each process runs in it's own memory space.

If you want to known the undefined behavior nature of accessing index into a part of memory not allocated to your program, try assigning values to `array[some_random_indexes]`.

Comment: Well, it can be assigned to some other program, but doesn't have to. In most cases it's this program memory, but you can be changing value of some other variable.

Answer (score 1):

To read or write outside the bounds of an array is defined in the standard as "Undefined Behaviour". The compiler is not required to detect it, but some do as a warning. The runtime is allowed to do anything including detecting an error, pretending it didn't happen, or even formatting your hard disk. Let's hope it doesn't!

In this case we can guess that the allocated storage is slightly longer than 6 ints. For your interest I suggest you try your program with indexes of 7,8,9,etc and eventually something bad will happen. C is just like that.

So the array bounds simply defines the size of an object inside which you get defined behaviour. That's all there is.